# Апартаменты в единственном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли употребить слово "апартаменты" в единственном числе — "апартамент"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словарь синонимов дает "апартамент"="комната" в таком синонимическом ряду: *Комната, горница, камера, каморка, покой, клеть, каюта, келья, апартамент*. 
В Википедии: *Апарта́ме́нт (фр. appartement - квартира, от итал. appartamento — комната) — комната или отдельное помещение в доме (квартира). В словаре Ушакова понятие «апартамент» — комната, преимущественно большая, покой... На рынке недвижимости и гостиничных услуг для зданий с апартаментами закрепилось название апартамент-отель[источник не указан 571 день] (апарт-отель). Апартамент-отель — комплекс номеров квартирного типа с возможностью аренды и полным набором гостиничных услуг. Обычно апартамент оборудован кухней и ванной комнатой.
В России апартамент как вид жилья появился сравнительно недавно, однако за этот период стало модно покупать апартаменты на море*

Стало быть, употребляемое словечко. Вот насколько это нормативно, трудно сказать. Можно ли употребить? Думаю, скорее да, раз есть такая тенденция в речи.

Comment: Это не тенденция. Скорее наоборот, форма единственного числа устаревает. Изобретения рекламщиков я не рассматриваю.

Comment: Возможно. Сначала не нашла ни в толковом, ни в орфографическом "апартамент" в ед. ч. Но таки оно там есть, только идет не отдельной статьей, а в статье "Апартаменты", где указано, что форма ед. ч. также существует. В общем, вполне литературное слово.

Comment: 1.В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Роман в шести частях. Части 1-3 (1864)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)   
    
Дело было в том, что Хлебонасущенский, устраивавший «для метрессы их сиятельства аппартамент» и забиравший все нужное напрокат, выплачивал поставщикам деньги ежемесячно из конторы Шадурских. 
  
[В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Роман в шести частях. Части 1-3 (1864)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→